Should my HVAC contractor be anchoring wiring by screwing anchors into my insulated ductwork?
I recently had a heat pump installed professionally.  The contractors reused the insulated ductwork (both intake and output) from the old gas furnace.  They sealed the old ductwork to the new unit with the fancy silver mastik tape.  So far so good, as far as I know.
When they ran the power to the unit, the conduit containing the wiring ran horizonally across the old insulated ductwork (output side), and I was surprised to see them just drill support brackets directly into the ductwork to anchor the conduit.  Seems idiotic to seal it with mastic one place and then punch holes in it 3 inches higher.  (But what do I know?)
Our unit stopped working a few days ago (because a connection burned out on one end of that same electric line...2 years after installation!).  They had to remove that conduit and reattach it.  Now there is a loud whistling sound coming from duct in the place they attached and reattached it.  I can change the loudness by pushing in on the insulation, but duct tape over the holes in the insulation does nothing.  Presumably the whistling is from the actual hole in the metal duct.  The noise is annoying to family members, but my biggest concern is the loss of efficiency and the fact that I'm blowing treated air into the insulation.
I'm sure that if I had raised concerns about drilling into the ductwork in the first place, they would have told me that they know the right way to do things and I don't.  If I raise a concern now, I'm expecting them to say that there is no problem with a hole in the duct.  Am I right to insist on their fixing the holes in my duct?  Am I right to suggest to them that drilling into my duct in the first place was a bad idea?

No, you're not right. Much. Maybe a tiny bit, but it's negligible.
It's common to see conduit and cable stays screwed to ductwork. Of course, the ductwork mounts are often screwed directly to the ducts. The ducts themselves are often connected by screws which protrude into the airflow.
Ducts aren't plumbing--they don't need to be 100% leak-free. It wasn't until recent years that ducts were even sealed to begin with. Those in my 1992 home aren't sealed at all.
Your experience with the whistling is not caused by the screw holes per se, but by imperfect repairs. Those should be easily fixed by adjusting the ductwork (adding screws, ironically) or by more carefully sealing new holes.
Regarding efficiency, keep in mind that all leaked heat remains in the home--it's just maybe not right where you want it. So, generally speaking, it's not really even an efficiency thing. It's a comfort thing. If, that is, you could even detect the heat misplaced due to a couple tiny holes. In the grand scheme of things they're almost nothing.

Thanks.  I'm happy to know I'm (mostly) wrong about drilling into the duct.  This is a 1976 home, and I don't think the ducts are sealed.  (However, since the furnace unit is in unconditioned space, any leaks there really are a loss.  That's why there is insulation around the ductwork at all.)  Can you elaborate on the "imperfect repairs"?  Do you mean that when they removed the old screws and put in new ones in a different place, they should have repaired the old holes?  I know they didn't do that, and it would be good to know whether I should insist.

You're right about the losses in your case. I doubt it's about screw holes, though. It's probably about a misaligned panel or joint that's not fit quite right.

You were right.  They found that the connection between the new furnace and the old ductwork had come loose.  When they sealed that, the whistling stopped.
